# Is it possible to use Gradle buildTypes for non android projects?

Tags: java, gradle

Since Gradle got quite popular among android developers and since the gradle-android plugin receives a lot of development the build system is now pretty easy to use and offers a lot of funcionality for developing android apps.

My question is, can these sweet things be also used if creating a pure java (i.e. non-android) project? Things like buildType do make sense in a non-android context, too.

I got quite accustomed to using Gradle but I have to make a pure java project and I want to enhance my knowledge of gradle (in using it a bit more sophisticated) and I dont want to get into another build system like maven or ant.